# Looking for a fast deterministic primality test for numbers above 64 bits

Tags: algorithm, math, primes

I have searched for ways to determinate if a number is prime or not, but most ways are either probabilistic (Miller Rabin) or for numbers smaller than 64 bits.

The other solution would be to use the brute force method with a few improvements or the sieves, but neither of those is very efficient when the numbers go above the 64 bit threshold.

Comment: Is there an upper bound to the length of the numbers? I.e. 65 bit, 28 bit, 20 million bit, ...?

Comment: For now I would like to be able to go at least to 128 bits if possible

Comment: Your computer has a finite probability of failure, thus giving an incorrect answer.  If you run enough M-R tests then you can ensure that a computer failure is more likely than the M-R tests giving you a composite number.  Alternatively have a look at the [AKS Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test), which is deterministic, but may be slow.

Comment: But how many would be "enough"?

Comment: @Robert.  There is a 25% chance that the M-R test will report a prime number as composite.  If you run `n` independent M-R tests then there is a `2^(-2n)` chance that a composite has been incorrectly flagged as prime.  So if you run the test 128 times on a number than there is a 1 in 2^256 chance that it is incorrectly flagged as prime.

Comment: @rossum: *There is a 25% chance that the M-R test will report a prime number as composite*. Hehe.

Comment: @James Yes, which is why you run multiple independent M-R tests to reduce the probability of an error.  By the time you have run it 64 or 128 times with different bases then you are in the area where your computer is more likely to have failed.

Comment: @rossum: No, you got it reversed. M-R *never* reports prime as composite. The 25% chance is the a composite is reported as prime.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for does not exist. There is no simple deterministic primality test that works always for all ranges of integers.

You already know about the Miller-Rabin test. It can be made deterministic on particular ranges; see [here](http://miller-rabin.appspot.com/) or [here](https://primes.utm.edu/prove/prove2_3.html) for details. If you assume the Riemann Hypothesis, then *n* is prime if *n* is an *a*-SPRP (a Miller strong pseudoprime) for all integers *a* with 1 < *a* < 2(log *n*)². A similar and somewhat better test is the Baillie-Wagstaff test; it is not deterministic, but no failures are known.

For numbers *n* up to 2<sup>128</sup>, it's not too hard to factor *n* − 1 and use a Pocklington test to prove primality. You can use trial division, or Pollard rho, or ECM to perform the factorization. There are also tests ([BLS75](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1975-29-130/S0025-5718-1975-0384673-1/)) that can prove primality based on a partial factorization. Larger *n* can also be proved prime using a Pocklington test, though sometimes the factorization becomes difficult.

For *n* up to about 10<sup>1000</sup>, a fast ECPP prime test is not unreasonable, though for the larger numbers in that range it might take a while. Beyond that, unless your number has some special form, you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: I will look into this Pocklington test

Comment: At my blog I have the [Lucas test](https://programmingpraxis.com/2010/02/02/proving-primality/) and [Pocklington test](https://programmingpraxis.com/2012/09/28/pocklingtons-n-1-primality-prover/).

Answer (score 4):

I will assume that what you want is a provably correct answer, rather than avoiding randomness altogether.

1. Run a few rounds of the Miller-Rabin primality test. If this fails, you know the number is composite, and you're done.
2. Factorize n-1. For this, simplest is the Pollard's rho algorithm. If that's not fast enough, use the Quadratic Sieve.
3. Check whether the factors are prime, using the same approach recursively. If they are composite, continue factorizing them.
4. Use the Lucas Primality Test: try to find a generator of the multiplicative group modulo n of order n-1. Pick a random number a, check that a^(n-1) = 1 (mod n), and that a^((n-1)/p) ≠ 1 (mod n) for all prime factors p of n-1. If this is true, a is a generator, and n is provably a prime number, so you are done.
5. If n is prime, the probability of success in finding a generator is (1-1/p<sub>1</sub>)(1-1/p<sub>2</sub>)... where p<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>2</sub>, ... are the distinct prime factors of n-1. This is at least 1 / O(log log n). So after O(log log n) attempts you should succeed in proving that n is prime.
6. If you keep failing in proving n is prime, go back to step 1. Maybe it's composite after all.

Comment: Actually I do want do avoid randomness altogether. I want to be 100% sure (save for computer mistakes) of the answer... However that seems very hard or impossible if I also want speed.

Comment: This algorithm uses randomness, but it only affects performance, not correctness. Once it produces the answer, the answer is 100% guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: If you want to have a deterministic version, you can just use "1,2,3,4,..." instead of random numbers, or some simple pseudo-random sequence. It's harder to prove anything about how long it will take in that case, but it will still work.

Comment: Well, but the thing about the Miller Rabin is that if it says a number is composite it is always right, but not if it says the number is prime, right? And if I go down the 1,2,3,4 route, won't it just be worse than the brute force method?

Comment: Yes, Miller-Rabin (step 1) can only prove that a number is composite, not that a number is prime.  Lucas test (step 4) is the opposite: it can only prove that a number is prime, not that a number is composite. So, if your number is composite, you get the answer via Miller-Rabin, while if your number is prime, you get the answer via Lucas.

Comment: The brute force trial division needs to find one specific number (the prime factor), which is what makes it slow.

Miller-Rabin and Lucas are much better, because many different bases work, not just one specific one.

Comment: It can be shown that if you pick your bases randomly, the Miller-Rabin will work (prove that the number is composite) at least 3/4 of the time, while Lucas method will work (prove that the number is prime) at least 1 / O(log log n) of the time. Both are "reasonably often".

If you go 1,2,3,4 in order, the proof doesn't quite work, but in practice you'll likely find a working base equally quickly too. There's just a lot of them, and there is no a-priori reason to think the small numbers are less likely to work.